# Dynamically show an image from a resource file in a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I am working with a Windows Forms application in Visual Studio 2010. I have a resources file, Flags.resx. I have uploaded images to the resource file, and want to show them in an Image control (picFlag). What is funny is THIS is super-easy, because my image files are strongly typed:

```
picFlag.Image = Flags.AE_Flag
```

But what I want to do, of course, is not. I want to dynamically provide the name of the image like this pseudo-code:

```
string strFlag = "AE_Flag";      
picFlag.Image = Flags[strFlag]
```

Any suggestions on the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following

```
var rm = new  System.Resources.ResourceManager("YourProject.Properties.Resources",
                                    typeof(Resources).Assembly);
var image = rm.GetObject("AE_Flag") as System.Drawing.Image;
```

hope it will help you